# In French, what is the meaning of « balai-là-où-je-pense »?

Tags: expressions

> ... sans l’affection de monsieur ***balai-là-où-je-pense***.

This is apparently a  jocular remark, but I wonder what it means, exactly? Does this entire phrase constitute an adjective qualifying « monsieur »?

Comment: Not that I have any clue about this phrase, but is there more context (for e.g. the purpose of determining if it's ironic)?

Comment: @LukeSawczak It's pretty clear, as a native you don't need any context to understand the part in bold (you should probably include "*monsieur*" in it though)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

L'expression en elle-même est pas courante (elle a dû être inventée pour l'occasion), mais elle se comprend très bien, elle se base sur plusieurs constructions ou concepts connus.

- "*Là où je pense*" c'est une partie du corps précise, qu'il est plus poli de désigner comme ça qu'en la nommant directement.
- "*Avoir un balai dans le cul*" est une expression qui signifie "être rigide, coincé, mal à l'aise".
- La construction "*monsieur [quelque chose]*" ou "*madame [quelque chose]*" sert à parler d'une facette de quelqu'un, souvent un défaut, comme si elle définissait la personne au point que c'est son nom de famille (un peu dans le même style que les livres [Monsieur madame](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monsieur_Madame)).

  Par exemple, "*Monsieur tout-le-monde*" est une allégorie de l'homme moyen, normal qui n'a rien de spécial par rapport aux autres. "Monsieur je-sais-tout", c'est quelqu'un qui va toujours corriger les autres et étaler son savoir, ce qui peut être très irritant. Après, on peut en construire avec à peu près ce qu'on veut.

Donc "*monsieur balai-là-où-je-pense.*" sert à désigner sans la nommer une personne qu'on qualifie de rigide et coincée.

Answer (score 10):

This comes from the colloquial phrase "avoir un balai dans le cul", which means "to be hung-up and haughty at the same time" (imagine eg the stereotype of an old professor who never smiles and insists on keeping formal habits in his class: his/her students would say "il a un balai dans le cul" about him). I think that's because it gives the image of someone standing up with his back extremely rigid ?
Then, it is mixed with an informal euphemism common in French: you will avoid mentioning intimate parts of the body (groin, bottom, sex, ...) by replacing the word by "là où je pense", ie "the place I am thinking about", and your interlocutor is supposed to understand what is the place you are thinking of... (eg: "il se gratte là où je pense" means "he's scratching his crotch").
So "monsieur-balai-là-où-je-pense" means "Mr. stuck-up-and-haughty"

Comment: Just seen your answer, it can indded be understood as "stuck up ". Makes sense as well.

Comment: This also jives with the identical English expression: To have a stick up one's ----.

Answer (score 1):

*Là où je pense* est un euphémisme pour parler d'une partie de notre individu qu'on ne nomme en général pas en public sauf besoin médical. Endroit sale et sombre (d'ailleurs en anglais on parle de là « où le soleil ne brille pas »).

Pour rejeter une proposition de quelqu'un, de façon **très** familière et **grossière**, on peut employer l'expression « mettre là où je pense » :

> Tu peux te le mettre là où je pense.*

Par extension « balayer là où je pense » c'est balayer là où ça restera très sale de toute façon.

« Monsieur balai-là-où-je-pense » peut être compris comme quelqu'un qu'on trouve excessivement moral et qui voudrait que tout soit toujours très propre. De façon moins grossière mais toujours familière, on pourrait dire « monsieur propre ».

* <sub>Just stick it up your ass.</sub>

Comment: Merci. Is it close to "Mr. 'you-know-who'" or "a certain someone"?

Comment: @Alone-zee Can't be. Impossible. *là où je pense* - can only be a place anyway - and this the usual euphemism for the place where the sun don't shine. You don't give much context but I gather *balaie* would have an *e* if my interpretation was correct, so I think the other answer suits best the way it's spelled.

Comment: Hi. There is no additional "e". I wonder if it is a typo, then?

Comment: @Alone-zee I don't think it's a typo.  *balai* noun, *balaie* verb ("monsieur qui a un balai là où je pense" vs "monsieur qui balaie là où je pense"")

Comment: @Laure Ça n'a pas grand chose à voir avec l'action de balayer, c'est une façon de dire qu'il a "*un balai dans le cul*". Ce n'est pas vraiment un souci de propreté (littéral ou figuré) ou de morale, c'est plutôt quelqu'un de rigide, coincé.